# How to make a browser an optional in protractor e2e configuration?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, webdriver, protractor, e2e-testing

I have a regression suite that will do an e2e on the deployed application in the respective environments.

We use a common webdriver that is running in a remote Windows 10 OS machine installed with MSEdge, IE, chrome and firefox browsers.

I need/like to verify my application in many browsers as much as possible. So that, I configured edge, ie, chrome in my protractor.conf.js as mentioned below:

```
multiCapabilities: [{
          browserName: 'MicrosoftEdge',
          platform: 'ANY'
        }, {
          browserName: 'internet explorer',
          platform: 'ANY'
        }, {
          browserName: 'chrome',
          platform: 'ANY'
  }],
```

its working fine with the remote machine where all the configured browsers are available. But, in local machine I do not have Edge browser since it is Win7 OS based.

Here is the question, is there a way to configure a browser as optional one (a good to be tested in). So that, devs running locally the scripts do not need to comment/uncomment these lines everytime. Most of all, I worry about testers more since they have minimum understanding of the protractor.conf.js.

**Note: MSEdge testing for my application is a good to have thing and not a must one.**

**Please do not answer like "Please comment the browser & run it" :) Just looking for options to make few browsers optional so that I do not need to worry about the webdriver configurations all the time. ;)**

Many Thanks in advance.

Comment: Make 2 configuration files.  One for local testing, and one for remote testing.

Comment: @Gunderson yes that is possible too but I feel that as duplication. as I mentioned in the question am not looking for workarounds but for new options or dynamic conf.

Answer (score 0):

I found a near solution to this one but not quite enough.

```
args: ['--multiCapabilities.browserName', 'chrome']
```

adding the above argument in the local e2e testing gulp task helps to override the configuration mentioned in the file.

**But here is the other problem. I can configure only one browser. :(**

Please update or provide new answer if there is a way to configure more browsers.

Thanks,
Ashok M A